# Hive UNION ALL operation giving FAILED: SemanticException

Tags: hadoop, hive

My Hive query was running fine with Hive 0.13 but when i switched to Hive 2.3, the following error started to occur:

```
FAILED: SemanticException 5:980 Schema of both sides of union should match: 
Column ln_id is of type string on first table and type int on second table.
Error encountered near token 'hourly_temp_for_prod'

org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.parse.SemanticException: 5:980 Schema of both sides of union should match: 
Column ln_id is of type string on first table and type int on second table. 
Error encountered near token 'hourly_temp_for_prod'
```

My query is trying to use `UNION ALL` between two tables, first table contains only the names of columns as strings and the other table contains the actual data related to those column names.

Comment: have you double checked the column data types ? both the left and right  tables should have same data types and same number of columns for the union all condition to work

Comment: The column names are same but the data types are different, but it was working on hive 0.13.